# Unable to find small syntax error in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

I cannot find the error(s) in this code. What I am trying to do is insert the formula in the column S, when "CN Equity" is used in the column A. I want the macro to run from row 6 to 69.

```
Sub fx()

Dim x As Long

x = 6

Do

    If InStr(1, (Range("A" & x).Value), "CN Equity") > 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S" & x).Formula = "=BDP("CADUSD BGN Curncy","LAST_PRICE")" & x
    End If

x = x + 1
Loop Until x = 70

End Sub
```

Comment: Examine `"=BDP("CADUSD BGN Curncy","LAST_PRICE")" & x`. Wrap the double quotes with another set of double quotes as its VBA escape character for quotes or use `Chr(34)` in place of quotes. what is the `& x` supposed to do at the end of the formula?

Comment: I tried using the Chr(34) route as you explained, but now get a compile error: Expected: end of statement

Using two double quotes also gives me that error.

Comment: well sorry but SO is not a debugging service... you have been pointed out what was wrong now go research VBA syntax + errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub fx()
    Dim x As Long
    x = 6
    Do
        If InStr(1, (Range("A" & x).Value), "CN Equity") > 0 Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S" & x).Formula = "=BDP(""CADUSD BGN Curncy"",""LAST_PRICE"")+" & x
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until x = 70
End Sub
```

**NOTE**

Replace the **+** in the formula with ***** or **&** if necessary.

Comment: It doesn't give me one

Comment: First try replacing **.Value** with **.Text**